# how to run an powerpoint add-in from the command line

Tags: command-line, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to open a powerpoint from the command line and run an add-in, or alternatively add an existing macro to a powerpoint programatically and then run the powerpoint with the macro.

I see the command line has an option to run the macro by using `/m macroName`, but I don't see any way to run an add-in. Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but /m macroName *might* work if the subroutine you want to run in the add-in is declared as Public.  Failing that, a VBScript run from the command line might be able to launch PPT, then call Application.Run on your subroutine.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg can you explain how you mean to run VBScript from command line? Do I point VBScript to the ppt file and then application.run on the add-in method name?  I've tried running /m with macroName but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VBScript user, so can't give you chapter and verse on how to acquire and automate a PowerPoint object using it, but once you've done so, the PPT object has an Application.Run method.  Here's a quickie example that I cobbled up based on a google search.  It works here:

Save this as a VBS file:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application") 
oApp.Run "PublicSubName"
```

Assuming there's a Public declared Sub PublicSubName subroutine in a loaded add-in, this will launch it.

Comment: SO AMAZING!! Thanks @Steve Rinsberg. That worked a treat. Sorry for taking so long to give it a go.

Comment: Glad it worked ... but "so long"?  < 1 day.  Pretty quick, I'd say. ;-)